# What could be Wrong with this if is_page Loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I'm working on a website. I'm using page.php to control all the pages even though they have different categories. All was ok on my local server (XAMPP), I could view all the pages, but when I uploaded online, the loops returned blank.

I decided to echo an "Hello" if page is true which worked fine. The main loop returns blank. Here is my code sample

```
<?php

  //this parts works
    if ( is_page( 10 ) ) {
          echo "hello";
        }           

        //This returns blank even when the category id and 
        if ( is_page( 10 ) ) {          

            $args = array(
                'post_type' =>'page',
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'cat' => 5
                );

            $new_query = new WP_Query( $args );

            while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post(); 

                echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="post_box3">

                        <div class="post_cont boxeq">
                            <a href="' the_permalink(); '">
                            <h3>' the_title(); '</h3></a>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>';

            endwhile; 
            wp_reset_postdata();        
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: you are missing an `echo` command in the `while` loop

Comment: you don't echo anything ? or return or anything, you just have a string. Am I missing something ?

Comment: please check database have page with ID 10

Comment: remove that   if ( is_page( 10 ) ) {  }

Comment: @sam remove if condition

Comment: No I can't remove the if condition. That loop is for the page_id.

Comment: Normal loops is working without the if condition. I decided to use the if condition to construct my page.php template instead of having separate template for each of the page which runs to 30.

Answer (score 0):

Either `echo` something or terminate PHP for a moment

```
    while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post(); 

      echo  '<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="post_box3">

                <div class="post_cont boxeq">
                    <a href="' . the_permalink() . '">
                    <h3>' . the_title() . '</h3></a>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>'

    endwhile;
```

or

```
        while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="post_box3">

                    <div class="post_cont boxeq">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> .">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                    </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
<?php
            endwhile;
```

Comment: wokring in localhost

Comment: @VasimVanzara It works in localhost but not on liveserver

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't moved an exact copy of your website on the host there might be possibilities that the `ID` which in your case is `10` or the `cat` which in your cast is `5` is changed. Try using slugs instead.

```
<?php

if ( is_page( 'your-page-slug' ) ) {
      echo "hello";
    }           

    //This returns blank even when the category id and 
    if ( is_page( 'your-page-slug' ) ) {          

        $args = array(
            'post_type' =>'page',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'category_name' => 'your-category-slug'
            );

        $new_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post(); 

            '<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="post_box3">

                    <div class="post_cont boxeq">
                        <a href="' the_permalink(); '">
                        <h3>' the_title(); '</h3></a>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>'

        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_postdata();        
    }

?>
```

Comment: Even with the page_slug, it didn't work. The first part where i said it should echo hello works, it's just the loop part that is not working

Comment: there is also a cat filter in the query have you tried verifying that? try `var_dump($new_query)` and see if the variable $new_query has something in it. If it does not then there is definitely a problem in your query

Comment: I tried your solution but it didnt work for me. What could b the problem and what's the possible solution?

Comment: Did you try `var_dump($new_query)`

Comment: Yes i did, it returned no value

Comment: This means there is a problem with the query you are running. Try playing with the parameters until you get results in your `var_dump($new_query)`